# Can derived object pointers be stored in an array of base class pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Assuming I have an array of base class pointers.
Can I store a derived class object pointer (derived from that base class) in this array? and can I do it the other way around?

Comment: Why dont you make it a practical question by providing some code?

Comment: Because it is a theoretical question from a college exam and no code was provided.

Comment: Yes you can store a `Derived*` in a `std::vector<Base*>` but not vice versa.

Comment: Think of it like this: You can put a `Dog` into an array of `Animal`, but you can't put an `Animal` into an array of `Dog` (no telling what that animal is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I store a derived class object pointer (derived from that base class) in this array?

Yes.

> and can I do it the other way around?

No.

Say you have:

```
struct Base
{
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
};

std::vector<Derived1*> ptrs;
Base* bPtr = new Derived2;
ptrs.push_back(bPtr);        // Not allowed.
                             // If it were, imagine the problems.
                             // You have a Derived2* in the guise of a Derived1*
```

Comment: Will I be able to do it even if the derived class has additional public functions?

Comment: You can. However, you cannot access the derived class members through the base class pointers. To access the derived class members, you'll have to cast the pointer back to the derived class pointer first.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed store a `Derived*` in an array of `Base*` (or any other data structure of `Base` pointers for that matter).

But the vice versa is not true as it violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle).